# What are the functional differences between Fabric Javascript SDK and Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Other than the fact that Composer makes deployment and testing of prototype business networks easier and the fact that we don't have to know golang to develop chaincode, what is the difference in the functionalities that these interfaces provide that may lead one to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article can probably provide you with the answers you need:

https://blog.selman.org/2017/07/08/getting-started-with-blockchain-development/

Hyperledger Composer is both an application development framework and set of powerful tools which simplifies and expedites the creation of blockchain applications and smart contracts that are ultimately executed on the Hyperledger Fabric blockchain. Composer has its own runtime, that is generic chaincode and hosts and interprets the business network deployed - so your smart contract need only use Javascript, not chaincode in Go a (which is Fabric's domain) s you mentioned. It also has a modeling facility to create your business network model and to define such controls as Access Control lists and queries to be executed.

This architecture link should help you with further understanding -> https://www.slideshare.net/SimonStone8/hyperledger-composer-architecture

Furthermore see the Hyperledger Composer docs, see here:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/

TO see the Hyperledger Fabric docs - see here:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/