# Is there any way to set multiple peers using Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Composer does not have a whitepaper as Fabric, I assume that they work in an analogous way, but I have some doubts.

Each resource as an asset is stored in a different channel?
How can I define the type of nodes(Ordering node, peer node...)?
When I update the bna, Does the blockchain do a fork?
Where is the bna saved?

I already serached a whitepaper but I have not found, if you find a paper with technichal information, please let me know

Comment: suggest to read the main answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152917/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-fabric-javascript-sdk-and-hyperledge and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505333/difference-between-hyperledger-composer-and-hyperledger-fabric and see the introduction in the Hyperledger Composer docs pages  -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction  and solution architecture page https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/solution-architecture.html